# Get Google Maps walking directions JSON instead of driving

Tags: ios, json, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, directions

I'm using this URL to get JSON directions (and showing in on map using `GMSPolyLine`):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=false
```

But the result it returns me is for driving and I want the user to choose between walking and driving.

Can anyone give me the URL for walking/choosing from walking or driving?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a URL-parameter `mode` to the value `walking`

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&origin=%@&destination=%@&mode=walking
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#TravelModes